# libevent: Reading all bytes from buffer

Tags: c, libevent

I have following read callback function `readcb` which is invoked on read event. My issue is, `bufferevent_get_input` is reading only 4096 bytes from the underlying buffer. How can I make it to read all bytes. I have used a variant also, given below as `readcb_variant`. It also reads only 4096 bytes and exists with `n = 0`, means no more bytes to read.

```
void readcb(struct bufferevent *bev, void *ctx){
    size_t bytesread;
    char buf[10000];
    struct evbuffer *input, *output;
    input = bufferevent_get_input(bev);

    bytesread = evbuffer_get_length(input);
    evbuffer_remove(input, buf, bytesread);

    printf("%zu\n", bytesread ); // prints 4096 for long (> 4096) byte stream
    do_some_cool_stuff(buf);
}


void readcb_variant(struct bufferevent *bev, void *ctx){
    char tmp[1000], buf[10000];
    size_t n, bytesread = 0;
    char *runner = buf;

    while(1){
        n = bufferevent_read(bev, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
        if (n <= 0){
            printf("%zu\n", n); // prints '0';
            break;
        }
        memcpy(runner, tmp, n);
        runner += n;
        bytesread += n;
    }
    printf("%zu\n", bytesread ); // prints 4096 for long (> 4096) byte stream
    do_some_cool_stuff(buf);
}
```

**Update**
After a close look into the source code of libevent, I found this line of code `#define EVBUFFER_MAX_READ   4096` at [source code](https://github.com/libevent/libevent/blob/master/buffer.c#L2198). Hard coded limit.

Comment: Can you try changing `%zu` to a `%lu`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Answer (score 1):

May be you could try to declare evbuffer_ptr and set it internal chain to first element of your evbuffer,

```
struct evbuffer_ptr ptr_ev;
struct evbuffer *buf;

ptr_ev.pos = 0;
ptr_ev._internal.chain = buf->first;
ptr_ev._internal.pos_in_chain = 0;
ptr_ev._internal.chain = ptr_ev._internal.chain->next;
```

(and loop until next hit null )

Also you maybe could try to use evbuffer_readln in a loop,

```
 char * evbuffer_readln(struct evbuffer *buffer, size_t *n_read_out,
            enum evbuffer_eol_style eol_style)
```

Comment: it Does not correct because of   evbuffer_readln just lookup \n at first chain